# clearTimeout() not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a menu with a submenu that slides out when you click on a button. I want it to slide back in after 7s if it hasnt already been clicked back in. I want to reset the timer when it is clicked back in so that it starts at the beginning if it is clicked again.

```
    $(".connect").click(function(){
     if($(".slidy-social").css("right") === "0px"){
       $(".slidy-social").animate({right: "200px"}, 250);
       var timer = setTimeout(function(){
         if($(".slidy-social").css("right") !== "0px"){
           $(".slidy-social").animate({right: "0px"}, 250)
         }
       }, 7000)
     }
     else{
       clearTimeout(timer);
       $("#social").animate({right: "0px"}, 300);
     }
   })
```

Comment: I've always had problems with timeout in this kind of a scenario. Have you tried interval ?

Comment: Note, you are calling `.animate()` on two different selectors, `.slidy-social` and `#social`. Is that what you are trying to achieve? Can you include HTML at Question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating a new `timer` variable every time the click listener function is called. You need to declare the variable outside the function so it will be the same variable each time.

```
var timer;
$(".connect").click(function() {
  if ($(".slidy-social").css("right") === "0px") {
    $(".slidy-social").animate({
      right: "200px"
    }, 250);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if ($(".slidy-social").css("right") !== "0px") {
        $(".slidy-social").animate({
          right: "0px"
        }, 250)
      }
    }, 7000)
  } else {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $("#social").animate({
      right: "0px"
    }, 300);
  }
})
```